# Property 'xxxx' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, angular2-aot

```
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

export class MasterVendorFormContactComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() formContactGroup: FormGroup;
// rest of the code 
}


<fieldset [formGroup]="formContactGroup" class="master-vendor-form-contact">
  <md-input-container class="master-vendor-form-contact__phone"
                      [dividerColor]="formContactGroup.controls.phone?.valid ? 'default' : 'warn'">
    <input mdInput placeholder="Enter phone" formControlName="phone">
    <md-hint align="end"
             *ngIf="!formContactGroup.controls.phone?.valid">
      Vendor phone number must be in (XXX) XXX-XXXX format
    </md-hint>
  </md-input-container>
  <!-- Rest of the code -->
</fieldset>
```

on compiling this code with aot it gives following error:

```
angular_app/src/$$_gendir/app/master-vendors/master-vendor-form-contact/master-vendor-form-contact.component.ngfactory.ts (465,73): Property 'phone' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }'.
angular_app/src/$$_gendir/app/master-vendors/master-vendor-form-contact/master-vendor-form-contact.component.ngfactory.ts (465,143): Property 'phone' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }'.
angular_app/src/$$_gendir/app/master-vendors/master-vendor-form-contact/master-vendor-form-contact.component.ngfactory.ts (476,77): Property 'phone' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }'.
angular_app/src/$$_gendir/app/master-vendors/master-vendor-form-contact/master-vendor-form-contact.component.ngfactory.ts (476,147): Property 'phone' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }'.
```

I tried following this approach:

**Don’t use form.controls.controlName, use form.get(‘controlName’)**

but here I have formContactGroup so it seems not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options, you can update to the latest typescript version. Since [version 2.2](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html) they allow the dot notation for types with string index signatures.

Or you can change your template, which makes more sense because that's the proper way to do it :)  [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControlName-directive.html):

```
<md-input-container [dividerColor]="formContactGroup.get('phone').valid ? 'default' : 'warn'">
```